# How to find greatest modulo in a given this

Tags: java, brute-force

What I am trying to do is find the greatest modulo in a list

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class p2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            int mod = i % m;
            ar.add(mod);
        }
        System.out.println(Collections.max(ar));    
    }
}
```

For example

```
5 3
```

Output would be
    2

because the greatest modulo from 1-5 when divided by 3 is 2

Is there a faster way to do this without the use of brute force?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of all numbers in range `1-n`, the largest modulo with `m` is `m - 1`, except if `n < m`, in which case it's `n`, so:

```
int maxModulo = Math.min(n, m-1);
```

The above of course assumes that `n >= 1` and `m >= 1`.